# How to Dual boot between Fedora 9 and Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have been trying unsuccessfully to dual boot a Fedora 9 and a Ubuntu 11.10 system. The system has a 200GB HD.

I installed Fedora 9 first on /dev/sda1 with a 80 GB partition. Installed the bootloader on 100 MB partition /dev/sda2. Then installed Ubuntu on /dev/sda4. However on booting up Ubuntu 11.10 does not display the bootloader.

Then I tried the other way round. Installed Ubuntu first and then Fedora next. However the Fedora Bootloader does not show Ubuntu as well.

I do understand that Fedora 9 uses the ext3 file system and Ubuntu 11.10 uses the ext4 file sytstem.Also they use different versions of grub. Fedora 9 uses grub1 and ubuntu uses grub2.

Could anyone please help me with the installation process to get this up and running?

Comment: There are many other SE sites where you can ask this question: http://superuser.com, http://unix.stackexchange.com, http://askubuntu.com. However, SO is not one of them.

Comment: I will post in the sites you mentioned in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-booting between different Linux OS's is really, really easy.  All you need to do is edit your Grub configuration.

Similarly, ext3 vs ext4 shouldn't matter: grub just looks at the partition.

One minor complication: Fedora 9 defaults to "grub"; your Ubuntu 11.10 defaults to grub2. Both versions allow multi-boot.  It's merely a question of which bootloader (grub, or grub2) you happen to have now.

And I assume you still have both OS's (one on /dev/sda2, the other on /dev/sda4).  Correct?

Assuming you have grub, here's a link with some samples menu.lst files that should help (your OS, drives and drive UUIDs will be different):

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=852414

title Fedora Core 9
configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/menu.lst 

title Ubuntu 8.04, kernel 2.6.24-16-generic
root (hd0,
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.24-16-generic root=UUID=58879049-46a9-4c86-9e0c-32d387b1b72a ro quiet splash
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.24-16-generic
quiet

title Ubuntu 8.04, kernel 2.6.24-16-generic (recovery mode)
root (hd0,
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.24-16-generic root=UUID=58879049-46a9-4c86-9e0c-32d387b1b72a ro single
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.24-16-generic

title Ubuntu 8.04, memtest86+
root (hd0,
kernel /boot/memtest86+.bin
quiet
```

Finally, here's more than you ever wanted to know about grub2:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#A.27.27grub.3E.27.27_Prompt_Booting

Comment: Thanks paulsm4, I will follow the steps you detailed.